# alertController not appearing in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, view, uialertcontroller, viewdidappear

I call the method in viewDidAppear but the alertController never appears and there doesn't seem to be a reason why.

```
func genderAlert()
    {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Quick Question:", message: "How would you describe yourself?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Party Animal", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
            UIAlertAction in
            print("Party animal Pressed")
        }
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Study Buddy", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
            UIAlertAction in
            print("Study Buddy Pressed")
        }
        alertController.addAction(okAction)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: I pasted your function into a test app and called it from `viewDidLoad`.  It displayed the alert.  Are you sure this code is being called?  Set a breakpoint to check

Comment: Above Working fine in `viewDidAppear` in iOS 10.1.1 Xcode 8.1 but not working in `viewDidLoad`. Getting the warning message `Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7fc756e09960> on <testing1.ViewController: 0x7fc756d05110> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`. Because the view still is in loading phase.

Comment: is this class is already presented ?

Comment: What self refers to in your code? Is it a UIViewController or something else like a UITableViewCell or anything?

Comment: this is all in my main ViewController